# Rsync and making sure all files have been transferred before applying the changes

Tags: linux, rsync

I was wondering if there is a way to tell rsync to only apply changes (delete, overwrite, create) only if all files in the file list transferred successfully.

Just to clarify, this would essentially be putting a transaction around the transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use a filesystem (btrfs, zfs) with snapshot-features:

- snapshot your current state
- rsync
- check exit code of rsync and rollback if needed

you can also enroll your own snapshots:

- make a  copy of the files (this becomes the working area)
- rsync to the working area
- check exit code of rsync and move working area over the original files if exit code was ok.

Comment: Instead of copies, you may want to use hard links to save time and space.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `--delay-updates` option, or if you want *really* atomic updates, the `atomic-rsync` script (included in Debian as `/usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/atomic-rsync.gz`).

Comment: I'm actually using the --backup option now and checking to see if the rsync fails. If so I attempt to restore the backup. Nothing much you can do if the network craps out and you can't connect to restore the backup. Pretty small chance though ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the 'rsync' man pages, you may be in luck *only* for deletes:

> Some options require rsync to know the full file list, so these options disable the incremental recursion mode. These include: --delete-before, --delete-after, --prune-empty-dirs, and --delay-updates. Because of this, the default delete mode when you specify --delete is now --delete-during when both ends of the connection are at least 3.0.0 (use --del or --delete-during to request this improved deletion mode explicitly). See also the --delete-delay option that is a better choice than using --delete-after.

Comment: That would satisfy deletes, however, I still need it to work for all files just in case there is packet loss or connection interruption. Great answer though. Thanks.